# Audio file streaming on mobile

Tags: android, server, client

How to play and stream audio files on mobile via android app through our own server. They both are located in the same wifi network. But audio files are only present on the server. Is there a way to stream those files on the client android like ( soundcloud)

Comment: means you need to stream audio in android app which is located into server?

Comment: Yes. This is the idea. Is it possible ?

Comment: check my answer below. by using that code you can stream audio.

Answer (score 1):

Videoview can play audio files also. try like this.

```
String urlAudio=""  // your server audio url path
 videoView = (VideoView) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
  mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlAudio));
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've [streamed music to my phone with ES File Explorer and a SAMBA share](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22706/what-are-the-options-for-streaming-music-from-pc-to-phone) in the past. The rest of the options in that post sound like even betters option however.

Comment: I want to know the code for developing an application for myself.

Answer (score 0):

By using AsyncTask you can stream audio file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button btn;
/**
 * help to toggle between play and pause.
 */
private boolean playPause;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
/**
 * remain false till media is not completed, inside        OnCompletionListener     make it true.
 */
private boolean intialStage = true;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    btn.setOnClickListener(pausePlay);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private OnClickListener pausePlay = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (!playPause) {
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
        if (intialStage)
            new Player()
                    .execute("http://www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3");
        else {
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        playPause = true;
    } else {
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_play);
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        playPause = false;
    }
}
};
/**
 * preparing mediaplayer will take sometime to buffer the content so  prepare it inside the background thread and starting it on UI thread.
 * @author piyush
 *
 */

class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Boolean prepared;
        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    intialStage = true;
                    playPause=false;
                    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_play);
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("IllegarArgument", e.getMessage());
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (progress.isShowing()) {
            progress.cancel();
        }
        Log.d("Prepared", "//" + result);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        intialStage = false;
    }

    public Player() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.progress.setMessage("Buffering...");
        this.progress.show();

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to control it from a server

Comment: means you need to play, pause, stop etc controls from server?

Comment: Yes. Thr data is on server too

Comment: i don't think this is best way but may be using GCM service. you can send message to the device and handle play, pause, stop etc controls.